# .htaccess for rewrite url

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess

hi let me explain in brief.

I have a url - "http://Domain.com/FolderName/Default.aspx?EditID=6" with query string.

I need to show that url like below

```
"http://Domain.com/FolderName/Name"
```

...that means I want to remove `"Default.aspx?EditID=6"` part from url and want to replace it with some name ...

Can you help me.

thanks a lot....

Comment: You have tagged the question with .htaccess which is a file that only applies on Apache servers however your example is using an aspx file (asp.net) which normally only runs on IIS (for asp.net you need to use a web.config and not the .htaccess file). 

Can you clarify are you using ASP.net under IIS or another language on Apache?

Answer (score 0):

This should work (but I haven't actually tested it):

```
# Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On
# Change requests that match "FolderName/Name/" to "FolderName/Default.aspx?EditID=6"
RewriteRule ^FolderName/Name/?$ FolderName/Default.aspx?EditID=6 [NC]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help...but remember that you have to write base url in your code to work with rewrite rule....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have mod_rewrite enabled:

```
RewriteEngine On

#prevent an infinite rewrite loop
RewriteRule ^Community/Default\.aspx - [L]

#rewrite the names
RewriteRule ^Community/([^/]+) /Community/Default.aspx?N=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

In your /Community/Default.aspx, you need to resolve EditName to EditID - e.g. look it up in some table you define.

Edit: Unfortunately, the rewrite module doesn't know which name maps to which ID (unless you make a separate rule for each ID, which doesn't scale at all). So the rewrite module passes the name as `N` to your Default.aspx and it is the script's responsibility to find out which ID is meant.

Comment: I appreciate your work but in my case still it's not working...
Actual URL is http://domain.com/Community/Default.aspx?EditID=6&N=ABCD
I want it as http://domain.com/Community/ABCD

Answer (score 0):

This is what I currently use to redirect as well as allow certain domains through with certain files for hotlinking:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?google.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|zip|js|css)$ - [F]
```